# A partly partial with io-ts

Tags: typescript, types

I'm having some issues with using `io-ts`. I've found that its really lacking documentation, most of the progress I've made is through GitHub issues. And no I don't understand the HKTs so no help there.

Basically I'm creating a type elsewhere, `type` which has a certain set of keys:

```
import * as S from 'io-ts/lib/Schema'

const someType = S.make(S => S.type({
  id: S.string,
  foo: S.string,
  bar: S.boolean
}))

type T = S.TypeOf<typeof someType>
```

And I need to transform this to a *partial* where some keys are still required. Say just the `id` key is still required, defining the type in TS would be like:

```
type PartlyPartial <T> = Partial<T> & { id: string }
```

Simple!

Now, I want to be able to do this at runtime through `io-ts` so that I can create a validator function with the `Guard` module. This is what I've got so far:

```
import * as G from 'io-ts/lib/Guard'

const propsBase = S.make(S => S.type({
  id: S.string
}))

const partial = S.make(S => S.intersection(
  someType(S) // needs to be partial,
  propsBase(S)
))

// So that this returns `true`
partial(G.guard).is({
  id: 'some id',
  bar: true
})
```

But the `someType(S)` defines the type as having all keys required, but none of them should be required.

This is driving me mad, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should tag the question with io-ts, since it seems the answer will depend on it.  Otherwise, consider editing the above example code so that it can dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and reproduce the issue.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I tried to tag with `io-ts` but failed. It says it does not exist and I need 1500 rep to create it...

Comment: Ah, fair enough (I probably should have checked for the existence of the tag)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no expert in io-ts, but looking at this more closely, I'm thinking it isn't a straightforward thing to implement. The methods in a `Schemable` build schemables out of other schemables.  The `type()` method takes a `properties` object whose keys are the keys of the desired object, and whose properties are schemables for each of the properties.  The `partial()` method takes the same `properties` object, but builds a schemable where the properties are optional.  You can see how these allow you to build the schemable; you have a `properties` object with all the keys you need to test for.

But given a schemable for type `T`, it isn't possible in general to convert it into one for `Partial<T>`.  The `properties` object that was passed into `type()` is not accessible in its result.  It's been lost; thrown away.  If all you have, say, is a type guard function that returns `true` if and only if it's given a value of type `T`, you can't use that function to make another one that produces `true` if and only if it's given a value of type `Partial<T>`.  You need more details of `T` from some source outside of the guard function, such as that `properties` object which is gone now.

So you can't do a straightforward composition of schemables to get this done.

---

The only way to do this would be to write your own `Schemable` that stores enough information about the `Schema` that calls it so that it can return a new schema where, say, the top-level call to `S.type()` is replaced with a call to `S.partial()`. Even that wouldn't be perfect, if you want to see your partial distribute across unions or down into intersections.  Essentially it would have to perform surgery on the `Schema`, unwrap a top-level call to `S.type()` to get at the lost `properties` object, and rewrap it with `S.partial()`.

It's easy enough to make one that turns *all calls* to `S.type()` into `S.partial()` (just replace your old schemable with a new one whose `type` property is a copy of the `partial` property), but that would end up making any nested objects partial as well as the top-level one.

Here's the horrible thing I did that kind of seems to work:

```
import { URIS, Kind } from "fp-ts/lib/HKT";
function partial<T extends object>(obj: S.Schema<T>): S.Schema<Partial<T>> {
  const partSchemable = <S extends URIS>(S: Schemable<S>) =>
    Object.assign({}, S, {
      type: (properties: any) =>
        Object.assign(S.type(properties), { properties })
    });
  return <S extends URIS>(S: Schemable<S>) => {
    let a = obj(partSchemable(S)) as Kind<S, T> & { properties?: any };
    return "properties" in a ? S.partial(a.properties) : a;
  };
}
```

It makes a new `Schemable` that keeps track of the `properties` object passed into its `type()` method and adds it as a property to the result.  Then, if the top-level result `a` has such a `properties` property, we return `S.partial(a.properties)` on it instead of `a`.

We can test that it works as follows.  First I'll augment `someType` with a nested object so we can prove to ourselves that only the top-level `S.type()` becomes converted to `S.partial()`:

```
const someType = S.make(S =>
  S.type({
    id: S.string,
    foo: S.string,
    bar: S.boolean,
    baz: S.type({ a: S.string })
  })
);
```

Then I'll make `myPartialType` (which is what you were calling `partial`):

```
const myPartialType = S.make(S => S.intersection(partial(someType)(S), propsBase(S)));
```

And finally a test function (using a `log()` function that puts stuff in the browser window in my stackblitz code I'll link at the bottom):

```
const test = (x: any) => {
  log(JSON.stringify(x), myPartialType(G.guard).is(x));
};

test({ foo: "" }); // false
test({ id: "", foo: "" }); // true
test({ id: "", foo: "", bar: "" }); // false
test({ id: "", foo: "", bar: false }); // true
test({ id: "", baz: {} }); // false
test({ id: "", baz: { a: "" } }); // true
```

So, those work.  Yay?  I guess.

---

My question here is: how badly do you need this?  Given your example code and what needs to be done to begin to approach a general-purpose `partial()`, I'd strongly recommend just making two versions of the schema in the first place, like this:

```
const props = <S extends URIS>(S: Schemable<S>) => ({
  id: S.string,
  foo: S.string,
  bar: S.boolean,
  baz: S.type({ a: S.string })
});

const someTypeRequired = S.make(S => S.type(props(S)));
const someTypePartial = S.make(S => S.partial(props(S)));
const easierPartialType = S.make(S =>
  S.intersection(someTypePartial(S), propsBase(S))
);
```

Here we've held onto the `properties` object ourselves so we could use it twice later, instead of the mess needed to recover it after throwing it away.  It produces the same results as before:

```
easierTest({ foo: "" }); // false
easierTest({ id: "", foo: "" }); // true
easierTest({ id: "", foo: "", bar: "" }); // false
easierTest({ id: "", foo: "", bar: false }); // true
easierTest({ id: "", baz: {} }); // false
easierTest({ id: "", baz: { a: "" } }); // true
```

but this version is much less error-prone.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Stackblitz link to code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ar8ved)

Comment: This answer is amazing and very elaborate. Thank you so much! I think I'll opt for the latter solution, and consume the properties rather than the schema itself.